# Excel VBA autofilter uncheck/exclude items

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

quick question, how can I exclude an item in a list through VBA. Have been working on a sheet that automatically prints out a list without a certain date on it.

```
   Rows("2:2").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$H$1000").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Hans"
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$H$1000").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="open"
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$H$1000").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="<>1/0/1900", Operator:=xlFilterValues
      ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
     IgnorePrintAreas:=False
         Rows("3:3").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
```

Problem is that the criteria does not work with the date 0-1-1900 to filter it out. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using the **Macro Recorder** and model your code on the Recorder's code.

Comment: You can't use operators to set the criteria, the only way is to list all the options you want to include, see http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2010/12/15/excel-autofilter-with-criteria-in-a-range/

Comment: @MátéJuhász is this information correct? Maybe for strings but for numbers when I use operators to set criteria they work w/o any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0-1-1900 is a date that does not exist. This might be the problem.

Just use

```
Criteria1:=">1/1/1900"
```

and it should word fine.

Comment: Fixed my problem, thanks! One question though, if I would like to exclude the date 1-1-1900, then my code should be
{criteria1:="<>1/1/1900"}
?

Comment: you can also use `Criteria1:="<>0"` where 0-1-1900 is actually date format of 0